# Redirect me to :[port]/[whatever I type]

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an app running on `localhost:8080` , I configured Nginix to make it run on `localhost/`

And I have another app running on `localhost:3000`

What I want to do is to redirect me to `localhost:3000/[whatever]` when I originally go to `localhost/[whatever]`

Something similar to this:

```
location /[SOMETHING] {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/[THAT_SAME_THING_ABOVE];
}
```

Is it possible to configure Nginx to do this behavior? if so how?
Thanks

Comment: Won't that break the formerly-8080 app?

Comment: The app running on 8080 is a single page, so 8080/anything doesn't even exist now

Comment: Then familiarize yourself with http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't proxy the app through nginx?  Doing that will result in a much more reliable and scalable configuration.

Comment: Let's say `localhost/something` would redirect me to the app running on `:3000` if I reverse proxied it. Then what is supposed to be `localhost/[whatever]` would be `localhost/something/[whatever]`. It isn't that bad but I would go for the first option if it's technically possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wanto to use:

```
location = / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000
}
```

See [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) docs.